# What happened to the outriders during "Avengers: Infinity War"?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Last time we saw of [them](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Outriders_(Race)), they were fighting against the Wakandans and the Avengers in [Wakanda](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wakanda), and there was still a number of them.

Now, just after Thanos' snap, we see the Wakandans being dusted away, but not even a single outrider is in sight:

[image: Wakandans in the battlefield]

[image: single Wakandan]

Now, it's pretty odd to not have even a single one of them in sight, when clearly the fight was still on and the battle was not over.

*(...because if they had been defeated, all the other Wakandans, or at least M'baku, would've gone to aid the Avengers in their fight with Thanos)*

What happened to them?
Were they dusted? Did they retreat? Were they defeated?

Comment: I don't have anything too detailed in terms of an answer, but I have heard that Hawkeye/Ronin is hunting them down, and that's what he's just killed in the trailer when Black Widow apparently locates him in Japan.  Not definitive enough to provide an answer to the question though...

Comment: @Dave but what could be the reason for Barton to hunt/kill them?

Comment: @Vishwa Anger as his family all dusted in front of him?  That's pure Endgame speculation though, albeit based on the trailers released showing happy Clint with his family.  I expect he'd quite happily just hunt down anyone/thing he could determine was involved.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, some of them were dusted**. Half of the entire universe was dusted away **(no exceptions)**. They weren't important enough to dust away "on-screen". Also, Thanos wouldn't need an army anymore since he had already achieved his goal.

My guess would be that Thanos even killed half of the population of the Outriders' planet when Thanos went there to get his army.

Comment: Do you have any evidence they were 'dusted'? Its possible that it happened to some of them, but for all we know they are still alive.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe-Levi Edited the answer for "Some of them".

Comment: **They weren't important enough to dust away "on-screen"**, how can you tell they were not important? They played a huge part at the battle in Wakanda

Comment: @Vishwa the outriders are literally mindless monsters that killed themselves without hesitation to attack the wakandans, they are literally **cannon fodder** and not worth dusting screen time compared to any other character we know, why waste dusting screen time on monsters we don’t care about individually or even en mass?

Comment: @morbo by that theory, wakandans (except main characters) would be the same, but we saw them right? anyway, I'm not sure about mindless, but they were determined to do whatever the task they were assigned to do. **monsters we don’t care** people do care, that's why this question is here. thanks anyway for the reply

Comment: Nah, this doesn't make sense. They can't just exclude certain characters, important or not

Answer (score 0):

https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Outriders

> At first, the heroes are being overwhelmed as they are too many
>   Outriders to fight back. Fortunately, Thor arrives to the rescue,
>   bringing in two Guardians of the Galaxy (Rocket Raccoon and Groot) and
>   a new powerful weapon called Stormbreaker, allowing the heroes to
>   finally defeat the Outriders and kill them all as well as the Black
>   Order, allowing enough time for the Scarlet Witch to destroy the Mind
>   Stone.

Comment: That "source" is fan written and as such unsourced speculation.

Comment: That isn't a valid source.